# VBA check if HTMLDivElement exists on page before proceeding

Tags: vba, getelementbyid

```
Set doc = ie.document
**Check Here for Data element**
Set fname = doc.getElementById("data")
```

I want to verify that the Element `"data"` actually exists before to setting the variable = to it.
would an `if` work and how would I structure the `if` to look at `doc` and verify that the element `"data"` exists

`doc` is declared as `HTMLDocument`

`fname` is declared as `HTMLDivElement`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you'd typically do it:

```vb
Set doc = ie.document
Set fname = doc.getElementById("data")

If fname is nothing then
    'was not found on the page
else
    'found
end if
```